# Does Stripe have any tool to send custom emails?

Tags: stripe-payments

I have a very quick question

Does Stripe have any tool to send custom emails when someone makes a payment?

For example… I am selling an e-book in my web and I want that when the customer pays then the stripe sends him the e-book, is that even possible?

(I’m talking about the Stripe dashboard tools, no code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short no. Stripe will only let you know if the transaction was approved or not. your website needs to handle the actions from that point on. They can however send a receipt to the customer of the payment made. This can be coded using the optional variable `receipt_email`

You can find very helpful information on their API integration [here](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/object)

If using a platform like Shopify/WordPress etc... you can add plugins that will do this for you. If you are building your website yourself use the response Stripe will give you to redirect the user to a page where they can download the e-book.
(Might be a bit more complex than this but you get the idea)

```
Customer pay
If (approved)
   `redirect to download page
else
    try payment again
```

This is an oversimplified version.

Companies like Stripe and Payment companies, do not host any files such as e-books for clients.